# Azure push notifications for WinForms project

Tags: winforms, azure, push-notification, signalr

I have an Azure web app that has an RESTful API located in a virtual directory. The API interfaces with an Outlook addin that I have created.

The primary function of the Addin is to track email(s)..either have these emails been opened or any links in the emails have been clicked or not.

A few months ago I had developed a small EXE program where I continuously made an API call to see if there were any new events for a particular email. This presented an issue because the instance of the SQL server DB that I had was being saturated with these calls (where eventually it would cause my other queries to cause timeouts).

So the decision was made to stop polling the db for any new events.

I've began some research on push notifications..and I'm led to WNS (Windows Push Notification Services).

I've also saw a few tutorials and I've basically set up an Azure push notification.

However I can't seem to find any solid/concrete example of getting this thing to work with a WinForms application. I've seen some tutorials where devs were able to send it to native WindowsApps.

However, I can't find anything on WinForm projects.

My question more is, am I going down the right path? Or should I be looking for other alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

See if [this sample on GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-notificationhubs-samples/tree/master/dotnet/SendRestExample) helps. The sample is not exactly a `WinForms` app, but a console one written for `.NET`. However, it should be pretty easy to adapt [the code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-notificationhubs-samples/blob/master/dotnet/SendRestExample/SendRestExample/Program.cs) to your needs if I understand the problem correctly.

Comment: Didn't quite work as expected. Although I ended up coding the solution using SignalR.

Comment: I believe this repo on GitHub contains examples of "sending notifications from console" not receive, which is what the question seems to be about. Good to know though.